# How can I set a size for a Tkinter window using ```import Tkinter``` instead of ```from tkinter import *```?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is not mine, it is from Byan Oakley

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I dont see any `root = Tk()` so I can't use the `.geometry` and I think that `.geometry` is not included when using `import tkinter` so I can't set a size for the window. Since there are 3 different pages, would I have to set a size for each page or can a global size be set? I'm new to python and started to get into tkinter 2 days ago, thanks for any help!

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method), ***...set a size for each page...***: Your pages are of type `Frame`, window size can only set on a `Toplevel` widget. Your page, `Frame`, resize accordingly if layout with the relevant option to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app = SampleApp` is defined at the bottom. If you call `app.geometry()` immediately after, it works.

If you follow the code, you arrive in `class SampleApp()` which is inherited from `tk.Tk`. Therefore, here you can also put `geometry()`, but now as `self.geometry()` because this class IS a `tk.Tk` object which *does* have the `geometry` property.

I agree that -at first sight- it may be a bit confusing because in many cases you'll see something like `root = tk.Tk()` at the beginning, so you could refer to `root` (or app, or master). But it is completely valid though.

Answer (score 0):

The way the imports are done is largely irrelevant. No matter how you import tkinter, to change the geometry of any tkinter window you call the `geometry` method of the window.

In this case the root window is `app` because `SampleApp` inherits from `Tk`.

From outside the class:

```
app = SampleApp()
app.geometry("800x600")
```

Or, inside the `SampleApp` class:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.geometry("800x600")
        ...
```